# Optimal way of aggregating geographic points with Python/Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

I would like to convert a long list of lat/long coordinates to the US state (or county) they belong to. One possible solution, given that I have the state geometries, is to check each points against all the states.

```
for point in points:
    for state in states:
        if point.within(state['shape']):
            print state.name
```

Is there a more optimized way to do this, possibly in O(1)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Rtree](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Rtree/) as a spatial index to very quickly identify the point in a bounding box of zero or more polygons, then use Shapely to determine the polygon that the point is within.

Similar to this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/14804366/327026

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
from rtree import index

# List of non-overlapping polygons
polygons = [
    Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0)]),
    Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)]),
]

# Populate R-tree index with bounds of polygons
idx = index.Index()
for pos, poly in enumerate(polygons):
    idx.insert(pos, poly.bounds)

# Query a point to see which polygon it is in
# using first Rtree index, then Shapely geometry's within
point = Point(0.5, 0.2)
poly_idx = [i for i in idx.intersection((point.coords[0]))
            if point.within(polygons[i])]
for num, idx in enumerate(poly_idx, 1):
    print("%d:%d:%s" % (num, idx, polygons[idx]))
```

If you dissect the list comprehension, you will see that `list(idx.intersection((point.coords[0])))` actually matches the bounding boxes of two polygons. Also, take note that points on the boundary like `Point(0.5, 0.5)` will not match anything with `within`, but will match both for `intersects`. So be prepared to match 0, 1 or more polygons.

Comment: Hi, @MikeT. Do you have an idea about how to use this to optimize this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761151/get-points-within-a-distance-to-another-python-spacial-structure-optimization#35761151 Thank you.