# Why is it taking forever to check if points are in shapes?

Tags: python, shapefile

I have about 1000 coordinates and 3000 shapes. My goal is to see if a coordinate falls within each shape:

```
import pandas as pd
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape

coords = pd.read_csv("coords.csv")
areas = shapefile.Reader("./areas")
shapes = areas.shapes()

for a, b in zip(coords["a"], coords["b"]):
    for i in shapes:
        if (Point((a, b)).within(shape(i))):
            print("in shape")
```

Test prints show that there are heaps of calculations going on but the loop just won't end. For such a small amount of coordinates and shapes I believe it is to do with my code.

Comment: The maths involved in checking if a point is wiithin a shape can be quite costly which is why bounding boxes are usually used within games

Comment: Also, "forever" isn't a measurable time

Comment: @unutbu Wouldn't it be only 1000 coords * 3000 shapes?  Where does the additional 1000 come from?

Comment: John Gordon is right, only 3.000.000 call of within(). Can you measure the time for one dataset? Just to give us some hints how costly theese operations are?

Comment: I changed it to try every coordinate against just one shape. The time: `0.04166412353515625`
The reason for asking is that this is part of a larger piece of an assignment so the fact it's taking more than a couple seconds means I've taken the wrong approach.

Comment: Related: [Faster way of polygon intersection with shapely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697442/faster-way-of-polygon-intersection-with-shapely)

Comment: @JohnGordon: Oops, you are correct.