# Efficiently count intersections of each polygon in a list with polygons in another list using Shapely

Tags: python, shapely

How can I simplify this for loop with a list comprehension and get more speed?

```
import numpy as np
import shapely

#buffer_original_points --> shapely polygons in a list
#raster --> shapely polygons in a list


raster_array = np.zeros((len(raster)))

for i in range(0, len(buffer_original_points)):
    for j in range(0, len(raster)):
        if buffer_original_points[i].intersects(raster[j]) or raster[j].contains(buffer_original_points[i]):
            raster_array[j] += 1

raster_array = raster_array.reshape(rows, columns)
```

I tried this, but the raster_array result was wrong and is filled with ones:

```
raster_array=[raster_array[j]+1 for i in range(0, len(buffer_original_points)) for j in range(0, len(raster)) if (buffer_original_points[i].intersects(raster[j]) or raster[j].contains(buffer_original_points[i]))]
```

Comment: This comprehension just returns values and doesn't change the values in `raster_array`. Since you wan't to change a variable inside the loop, a loop seems to be the right approach.

Comment: @Georgy Thanks for your support. Could you please give me some advise to implement Mike T 's solution in my case? I am a little bit overwhelmed with the topic Rtree and do not understand how to use it in my case. My aim is to build a matrix where the cell value depends on the number of points which lay in a raster cell.

Comment: I suggest trying the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43105613/7851470) instead, so you won't have to install other libraries. Initialize the `STRtree` by the list of raster polygons, then iterate over `buffer_original_points` and use the `query` method to get those raster polygons that intersect with the polygon on the current iteration. To keep the track of counts you could also use `collections.Counter` with `raster`s as keys, which you would convert back to an array of counts in the end.

Comment: @Georgy please correct me if I am wrong. The STRtree gets initialized with `s=STRtree(raster)`. After that I queried the results with a list-comprehension and stored the results in a list `result=[s.query(buffer_original_points[i] for i in range(0,len(buffer_original_points)`.  Then I tested to see if any result gets true with `[raster[i] in result for i in range(0,len(raster))` but the whole list is **false**. Sorry for my misunderstanding but I am a novice.

Comment: The first list comprehension doesn't look right, there are missing parentheses. The second one won't work as expected because `result` is (most probably) a list of lists of polygons, but you check for the presence of `raster[i]` in it as it was a flat list of polygons. I sketched out a notebook with an example of how you would do it. Take a look: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/LostFan123/f6c46d304681b0262823637dd5e3ea5d

Comment: Big thanks @Georgy. Your notebook helped me out enormously! From two minutes runtime to <1 sec. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try the following:

```
raster_array = [sum([buffer_original_points[i].intersects(raster[j]) or raster[j].contains(buffer_original_points[i])) for i in range(0, len(buffer_original_points))] for j in range(0, len(raster))]
```

But I'm not sure this is not a good coding practice due to the reduced clarity.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but your code snippet returns me a syntax error and I can't figure out where the problem occurs.