# Generate coordinates inside Polygon

Tags: python, numpy

I want to bin the values of polygons to a fine regular grid.
For instance, I have the following coordinates:

```
data = 2.353
data_lats = np.array([57.81000137,  58.15999985,  58.13000107,  57.77999878])
data_lons = np.array([148.67999268,  148.69999695,  148.47999573,  148.92999268])
```

My regular grid looks like this:

```
delta = 0.25
grid_lons = np.arange(-180, 180, delta)
grid_lats = np.arange(90, -90, -delta)
llx, lly = np.meshgrid( grid_lons, grid_lats )
rows = lly.shape[0]
cols = llx.shape[1]
grid = np.zeros((rows,cols))
```

Now I can find the grid pixel that corresponds to the center of my polygon very easily:

```
centerx, centery = np.mean(data_lons), np.mean(data_lats)
row = int(np.floor( centery/delta ) + (grid.shape[0]/2))
col = int(np.floor( centerx/delta ) + (grid.shape[1]/2))
grid[row,col] = data
```

However, there are probably a couple of grid pixels that still intersect with the polygon. Hence, I would like to generate a bunch of coordinates inside my polygon (data_lons, data_lats) and find their corresponding grid pixel as before. Do you a suggestion to generate the coordinates randomly or systematically? I failed, but am still trying.

Note: One data set contains around ~80000 polygons so it has to be really fast (a couple of seconds). That is also why I chose this approach, because it does not account the area of overlap... (like my earlier question [Data binning: irregular polygons to regular mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934959/data-binning-irregular-polygons-to-regular-mesh) which is VERY slow)

Comment: Looking at your previous question, which has a helpful figure to show the scales, it seems every grid pixel should be associated with exactly one polygon, in which case, you could find the center of the grid pixel, and associate it with the closest polygon center.

Comment: That is a good point. Unfortunately some Polygons share are large portion of the grid pixel and hence I take the mean value of them. What I did not mention above is that I sum all the values that fall into one grid pixel and then take the mean from the total count. That is a bit more realistic I think.

Comment: Just forgot... by finding the closest polygon center for each grid pixel the computation should go up dramatically? So I think it's better to go the other way around.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I would think matching distances would be significantly quicker than calculating overlap.  I do something similar in my research and it's not too slow, but I only have ~1k particles.

Comment: I will definitely look more into using the distances, maybe I got you wrong. Though, at the moment the above stated code does not calculate any overlap. It just takes 1 second so far since it is just assigning values. Also, the polygons don't look like squares, so the center may be closeer to some sides than to others.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to test the following approach to see if it is fast enough. First, you should modify all your lats and lons into, to make them (possibly fractional) indices into your grid:

```
idx_lats = (data_lats - lat_grid_start) / lat_grid step
idx_lons = (data_lons - lon_grid_start) / lon_grid step
```

Next, we want to split your polygons into triangles. For any convex polygon, you could take the center of the polygon as one vertex of all triangles, and then the vertices of the polygon in consecutive pairs. But if your polygon are all quadrilaterals, it is going to be faster to divide them into only 2 triangles, using vertices 0, 1, 2 for the first, and 0, 2, 3 for the second.

To know if a certain point is inside a triangle, I am going to use the barycentric coordinates approach described [here](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html). This first function checks whether a bunch of points are inside a triangle:

```
def check_in_triangle(x, y, x_tri, y_tri) :
    A = np.vstack((x_tri[0], y_tri[0]))
    lhs = np.vstack((x_tri[1:], y_tri[1:])) - A
    rhs = np.vstack((x, y)) - A
    uv = np.linalg.solve(lhs, rhs)
    # Equivalent to (uv[0] >= 0) & (uv[1] >= 0) & (uv[0] + uv[1] <= 1)
    return np.logical_and(uv >= 0, axis=0) & (np.sum(uv, axis=0) <= 1)
```

Given a triangle by its vertices, you can get the lattice points inside it, by running the above function on the lattice points in the bounding box of the triangle:

```
def lattice_points_in_triangle(x_tri, y_tri) :
    x_grid = np.arange(np.ceil(np.min(x_tri)), np.floor(np.max(x_tri)) + 1)
    y_grid = np.arange(np.ceil(np.min(y_tri)), np.floor(np.max(y_tri)) + 1)
    x, y = np.meshgrid(x_grid, y_grid)
    x, y = x.reshape(-1), y.reshape(-1)
    idx = check_in_triangle(x, y, x_tri, y_tri)
    return x[idx], y[idx]
```

And for a quadrilateral, you simply call this last function twice :

```
def lattice_points_in_quadrilateral(x_quad, y_quad) :
    return map(np.concatenate,
               zip(lattice_points_in_triangle(x_quad[:3], y_quad[:3]),
                   lattice_points_in_triangle(x_quad[[0, 2, 3]],
                                              y_quad[[0, 2, 3]])))
```

If you run this code on your example data, you will get two empty arrays returned: that's because the order of the quadrilateral points is a surprising one: indices 0 and 1 define one diagonal, 2 and 3 the other. My function above was expecting the vertices to be ordered around the polygon. If you really are doing things this other way, you need to change the second call to `lattice_points_in_triangle` inside `lattice_points_in_quadrilateral` so that the indices used are `[0, 1, 3]` instead of `[0, 2, 3]`.

And now, with that change :

```
>>> idx_lats = (data_lats - (-180) ) / 0.25
>>> idx_lons = (data_lons - (-90) ) / 0.25
>>> lattice_points_in_quadrilateral(idx_lats, idx_lons)
[array([952]), array([955])]
```

If you change the resolution of your grid to 0.1:

```
>>> idx_lats = (data_lats - (-180) ) / 0.1
>>> idx_lons = (data_lons - (-90) ) / 0.1
>>> lattice_points_in_quadrilateral(idx_lats, idx_lons)
[array([2381, 2380, 2381, 2379, 2380, 2381, 2378, 2379, 2378]),
 array([2385, 2386, 2386, 2387, 2387, 2387, 2388, 2388, 2389])]
```

Timing wise this approach is going to be, in my system, about 10x too slow for your needs:

```
In [8]: %timeit lattice_points_in_quadrilateral(idx_lats, idx_lons)
1000 loops, best of 3: 269 us per loop
```

So you are looking at over 20 sec. to process your 80,000 polygons.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! I can definitely learn from that! Though, the running time worries me a bit, since the binning of such satellite pixels should be ultra fast, in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a quick and dirty solution by simply calculating the coordinates between corner pixels. Take a look:

```
dlats = np.zeros((data_lats.shape[0],4))+np.nan
dlons = np.zeros((data_lons.shape[0],4))+np.nan
idx = [0,1,3,2,0] #rearrange the corner pixels

for cc in range(4):
    dlats[:,cc] = np.mean((data_lats[:,idx[cc]],data_lats[:,idx[cc+1]]), axis=0)
    dlons[:,cc] = np.mean((data_lons[:,idx[cc]],data_lons[:,idx[cc+1]]), axis=0)

data_lats = np.column_stack(( data_lats, dlats ))
data_lons = np.column_stack(( data_lons, dlons ))
```

Thus, the red dots represent the original corners - the blue ones the intermediate pixels between them.

[image]

I can do this one more time and include the center pixel (geo[:,[4,9]])

```
dlats = np.zeros((data.shape[0],8))
dlons = np.zeros((data.shape[0],8))

for cc in range(8):
    dlats[:,cc] = np.mean((data_lats[:,cc], geo[:,4]), axis=0)
    dlons[:,cc] = np.mean((data_lons[:,cc], geo[:,9]), axis=0)

data_lats = np.column_stack(( data_lats, dlats, geo[:,4] ))
data_lons = np.column_stack(( data_lons, dlons, geo[:,9] ))
```

[image]

This works really nice, and I can assign each point directly to its corresponding grid pixel like this:

```
row = np.floor( data_lats/delta ) + (llx.shape[0]/2)
col = np.floor( data_lons/delta ) + (llx.shape[1]/2)
```

However the final binning now takes ~7sec!!! How can I speed this code up:

```
for ii in np.arange(len(data)):
    for cc in np.arange(data_lats.shape[1]):
        final_grid[row[ii,cc],col[ii,cc]] += data[ii]
        final_grid_counts[row[ii,cc],col[ii,cc]] += 1
```

Comment: For cleanness, you should accept your own answer and post this as a new question. I haven't looked into your code in detail, but there are too many for loops for it not be vastly improvable.