# Avoid for-loops in assignment of data values

Tags: python, numpy

So this is a little follow up question to my earlier question: [Generate coordinates inside Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226755/generate-coordinates-inside-polygon) and my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15243767/1740928
In fact, I want to bin polygon data to a regular grid. Therefore, I calculate a couple of coordinates within the polygon and translate their lat/lon combination to their respective column/row combo of the grid.

Currently, the row/column information is stored in a numpy array with its number of rows corresponding to the number of data polygons and its number of columns corresponding to the coordinates in the polygon.

The whole code takes less then a second, but this code is the bottleneck at the moment (with ~7sec):

```
for ii in np.arange(len(data)):
    for cc in np.arange(data_lats.shape[1]):
        final_grid[        row[ii,cc], col[ii,cc] ] += data[ii]
        final_grid_counts[ row[ii,cc], col[ii,cc] ] += 1
```

The array "data" simply contains the data values for each polygon (80000,). The arrays "row" and "col" contain the row and column number of a coordinate in the polygon (shape: (80000,16)).
As you can see, I am summing up all data values within each grid cell and count the number of matches. Thus, I know the average for each grid cell in case different polygons intersect it.
Still, how can these two for loops take around 7 seconds? Can you think of a faster way?

Comment: This is more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not fully understand the shapes of your different grids, but you can maybe eliminate the `cc` loop using something like this:

```
final_grid = np.empty((nrows,ncols))
for ii in xrange(len(data)):
    final_grid[row[ii,:],col[ii,:]] = data[ii]
```

This of course assumes that `final_grid` is starting with no other info (that the count you're incrementing starts at zero).  And I'm not sure how to test if it works not understanding how your `row` and `col` arrays work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This little trick reduces the running time  to 4.5 seconds!

Comment: If you think about it longer, you can probably avoid looping through `ii` too, but I wasn't exactly sure how.

Answer (score 2):

I think numpy should add an nd-bincount function, I had one lying around from a project I was working on some time ago.

```
import numpy as np

def two_d_bincount(row, col, weights=None, shape=None):
    if shape is None:
        shape = (row.max() + 1, col.max() + 1)
    row = np.asarray(row, 'int')
    col = np.asarray(col, 'int')

    x = np.ravel_multi_index([row, col], shape)
    out = np.bincount(x, weights, minlength=np.prod(shape))
    return out.reshape(shape)

weights = np.column_stack([data] * row.shape[1])
final_grid = two_d_bincount(row.ravel(), col.ravel(), weights.ravel())
final_grid_counts = two_d_bincount(row.ravel(), col.ravel())
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Hadn't thought of a `bincount` approach, but it makes a lot of sense. Couldn't `histogram2d` be used to do the same?

Comment: Yes, histogram 2d is probably even more appropriate for this problem.

Comment: Thank you also for this post! I could indeed use it to speed it up!

Comment: I must say that the pure histogram2d and two_d_bincount is actually a bit slower than my code before.